# Segment display – Why selecting segment by GND

Tags: arduino, ground, display

I bought display and for my surprise it works same as display i already had. I must chose segment i want to light up by GND and not by output pin on my Arduino.

Is it normal or there is something what have to be done when working with this kind of displays?

For completeness, here is [data sheet](http://gme.cz/img/cache/doc/512/035/hd-a822rd-datasheet-1.pdf) (SD-36)

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

Comment: For clarity, please show which wire is ground and if possible post the datasheet for this display. Some are common cathode and some are common anode :]

Comment: Are you using series resistors when you connect your display? It extends lifetime considerably, from minutes without to years with them.

Comment: Your Arduino can both sink and source current. This means you don't have to use Arduino for low side switching (GND), you can also choose for high side switching (Vcc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is quite normal. Segment displays like that are usually available in both common anode and common cathode types. What you originally had was a common cathode type. What you have now is a common anode type.

[image: Segment display]

Common anode displays are sometimes preferred because you can easily drive them with a darlington driver array, like the [ULN2803](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/uln2803a.pdf):

[image: ULN2803 driving common anode LEDs]

The ULN2803 can sink quite a lot more current than a microcontroller GPIO pin, and so drive large, high brightness displays.

Comment: It's not a big deal but isn't the OP saying that the display he bought is the same as the one he already had i.e. both common anode?

Comment: @Andyaka - Perhaps. To be honest I found the question a little hard to understand. This was my best interpretation.

Comment: @Rocketmagnet: Your answer is totally ok. Thank you ;) The link you provided for driver is not working for me. Can you pls provide me with links to some introductions  for this kind of drivers