# Building LED cube using 74HC595N

Tags: 74hc595

I'm working with 8x8x8 single color led cube.(8x8 anode cols and 8 cathode rows)

I've done soldering and I have lots of 74HC595N chips. Of course you know one chip can deal with 8 anode lead of LED. So, I will use 8 74HC595s for that. This may work for 64 different OUTPUTs.

Then, **what about cathode? Can I use 74HC595 for INPUT?**(I think I can use just 8 different pins on Arduino or RPI)

One more question please, **I have 5V 2A adapter. Can I use this for cube without any other components?**

Thanks in advance and please understand lack of my knowledge about electronics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need resistors, of course, and I believe you can only source about 70mA per 74HC595N or something like that, so if you plan to ever light more than three LEDs at the same time that are driven by the same chip, limit the current accordingly (and don't expect the cube to be bright).

You probably want to drive your layers (cathodes, it seems from your description) via some transistors, possibly a Darlington array, like a UDN2981, similar to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/82025/25217.